# Question on the natural logarithm laws

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Can $3*\ln(x)$ can be written as $\ln(x^3)$ ?

There is a law that $\ln(x^3) = 3\ln(x)$, but does it apply in the reverse case? If not, why not?

Comment: Equality has this property.  If $A=B$, then $B=A$.

Comment: You might be making a mistake I see many students make - the symbol "=" means that the two sides are equal (the same), not that "I can proceed from the left-side to the right-side". Students often think in these procedural terms, and in that framework it's not clear that the "reverse" (as you put it) will also work. But really $\ln (x^3) = 3 \ln (x)$ means that the two sides are the same thing, so of course you can use the equality from left-to-right or from right-to-left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Just like the comment to your question, if we know two objects are equal, then the "reverse case" is also true.

Here is a more rigorous proof for fun: "Let $n \in \mathbb{R}$, $a \in (0,\infty) \backslash \left\{1\right\}$, and $x \in (0,\infty)$. Prove that

$$\log_a{\left(x^n\right)} = n\log_a{(x)}."$$

If we let $m = \log_a{x}$ then $a^m = x$.

Then $\left(a^m\right)^n = x^n$ and $\left(a^m\right)^n = a^{mn}$.

So $x^n = a^{mn}$ by transitivity.

In log form, we get

$$\log_a{\left(x^n\right)} = \log_a{a^{mn}} = mn = nm = n\log_a{x}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$. Since $3 \cdot log(x) = log(x^3)$, it follows that $log(x^3) = 3 \cdot log(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach:

Assume that $\log(x) = r \implies e^r = x.$

Then $\displaystyle e^{(3r)} = \left[e^r\right]^3 = x^3.$

Thus, $3r = \log(x^3).$

Thus $3 \times \log(x) = \log(x^3).$